# How to hide some strings with certain condition?

Tags: android, json

I have a simple yet a problem that I cannot solve. What I want to do with the program is to show the parentheses only when the string length is greater than 1 or when not null. However, the condition doesn't work. Are there some problems in my code?

```
String _name = json.getString("name");

if(_name.length()>3){
    _name = "("+_name+")";
}else{

}

map1.put("name", _name);
```

I want to save the string with parentheses only when the JSON data is not null or empty. But it doesn't seem to work. It shows the parenthesis all the time with empty space between them.

Comment: try it with String_name=""; in else condition and put the map1.put() into if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, "*show the parentheses only when the string length is greater than 1 or when not null*".

```
String _name = json.getString("name");

Put the below condition.

// Check null of string here. you can also check length here based on your condition.
if(_name != null && _name != "" && !_name.equalsIgnoreCase("") && _name.length() > 1 )
{
   _name = "("+_name+")";
}
else
{
   //Other stuff here
}
```

Comment: I figured the problem few mins ago , but I find your answer very readable and great !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String _name = json.getString("name");
                if(_name != null && _name.length()>3){
                     _name = "("+_name+")";
                }else{
                     _name = "";
                }
                map1.put("name", _name);
```